# Как получить ближайший целый час

Tags: java, android, android-alarm-manager

У меня есть задача: выводить уведомление каждый час. Чтобы решить эту проблему я пытаюсь использовать `AlarmManager`.

Вроде бы все разобрался, но не понял одного: а как получить ближайший целый час (к примеру, 13:00, если сейчас 12:34), чтобы задать начальную точку отсчета, а потом выводить сообщение каждый час?

То есть, я хочу получить что-то вроде такого:

```
mAlarmManager.setRepeating(RTC_WAKEUP, <начальная_точка_отсчета>, 3600 * 100, mIntent)
```

где `<начальная_точка_отсчета>` - это ближайший целый час.

---

Как получить ближайший целый час (желательно в миллисекундах)?

Comment: А время Вы как получаете?

Comment: @post_zeew, как нужно будет - так и получу.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, напрашивающееся-очевидное решение Вам не подойдет? Почему?

Comment: @post_zeew, что-то мне кажется, что я об этом решении не знаю... Единственное, что пришло мне в голову - в ответе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то требуется получить кол-во миллисекунд, прошедших от [точки отсчета](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) до времени, которое будет равно ближайшему целому часу (*простите за мой французский, но суть, думаю, ясна*).

Получить это кол-во миллисекунд можно так:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
    calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
    calendar.get(Calendar.DATE), 
    calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 
    0, 
    0);
long ms = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: Стоп. А чего, при использовании этого метода в 17:25, мне выдает 06:00, если должно быть 18:00?

Comment: @РостиславДугин, Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Только что лег спать и пришла идея в голову. Алгоритм получения ближайшего целого часа таков:

1. Получить текущее время в мс.
2. Получить остаток от деления этого времени на час в мс (60 * 60 * 100).
3. Отнять от часа в мс остаток.
4. Добавить к времени, полученному в п.1, время, полученное в п.4.

Выйдет так, что я сначала получу, сколько прошло минут (секунд, мс и т.д) от текущего часа и добавлю время, которое ему не хватает до целого числа.

Comment: Я может чего-то не понимаю, но почему бы просто не получить текущий час и инкрементировать его?

Comment: @post_zeew, а как? О.о

Comment: Ну типа того `int hours = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR);`.

Comment: @post_zeew, хм.. А я не знал, что так можно. Сейчас все-таки потопаю спать, а завтра разберусь.